# Image Processing in Android calling Garbage Collector

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing, garbage-collection

I am writing a custom grayscale conversion method:

```
public Mat grayScaleManual(Mat imageMat){
  Mat dst = new Mat(imageMat.width(), imageMat.height(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
  double[] bgrPixel;
  double grayscalePixel;

  for(int y = 0; y < imageMat.height(); y++){
      for(int x = 0; x < imageMat.width(); x++){
        bgrPixel = imageMat.get(y, x);
        grayscalePixel = (bgrPixel[0] + bgrPixel[1] + bgrPixel[2])/3;
        imageMat.put(y, x, grayscalePixel);
      }
  }

  return imageMat;
}
```

`Mat` is a class from the OpenCV4Android library. I know OpenCV has a built-in grayscaling method, but I want to make a comparison between my grayscale implementation and that of OpenCV.

This method always makes calls to the Garbage Collector. I know that the Garbage Collector is called when there are unused objects, but I do not think there are any unused objects in my code.

Why does this code keep calling the Garbage Collector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code you posted, `dst` is created and never accessed, nor is it returned by your function. When it goes out of scope at the end of the function, no references are left to `dst`, so the garbage collector is free to reclaim it.

To solve this, you can write the greyscale values to `dst`, and then return that instead. Otherwise, you are overwriting the image data inside `imageMat` with the greyscale pixels, but without changing the data type to `CV_8UC1`. This will corrupt the data inside `imageMat`.

To fix this problem, call `dst.put()` instead of `imageMat.put()`, and return `dst` instead. The line:

```
imageMat.put(y, x, grayscalePixel);
```

then becomes:

```
dst.put(y, x, grayscalePixel);
```

I should also note that you are using a different formula for greyscale than OpenCV does. You are averaging RGB values to calculate grey value, while OpenCV uses the following formula (from the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?#cvtcolor)):

[image: Greyscale Equation]

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
Mat dst = new Mat(imageMat.width(), imageMat.height(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
```

will allocate a new Mat object which will be discarded at the end of your method. This is probably the cause of your GCs in this method.